# Django CMS: Error while setting up django-cms

Tags: python, django, django-models, content-management-system, django-cms

I'm having a WSGI error while following the installation set up for django-cms from th [official documentation.](https://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/install.html#)

I ran test with `python manage.py cms check` and it was sucessful.

---

Checking django CMS installation

---

## Sekizai

- Sekizai is installed [OK]
- Sekizai template context processor is installed [OK]
- Sekizai namespaces 'js' and 'css' found in 'home.html' [OK]
  Plugin instances
  ================
- Plugin instances of 0 types found in the database [OK]

The plugins in your database are in good order [OK]

## Presence of "copy_relations"

All plugins and page/title extensions have "copy_relations" method if needed. [OK]

## PlaceholderField

PlaceholderField configuration okay [OK]

## OVERALL RESULTS

9 checks successful!

Installation okay

But when I try running server, I get this thread of errors.

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
July 22, 2022 - 08:47:41
Django version 3.2.14, using settings 'projcms.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\adedi\Documents\Dev\Projects\Django\dj-cms\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 13, in import_string
    module_path, class_name = dotted_path.rsplit('.', 1)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\adedi\Documents\Dev\Projects\Django\dj-cms\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 45, in get_internal_wsgi_application
    return import_string(app_path)
  File "C:\Users\adedi\Documents\Dev\Projects\Django\dj-cms\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 17, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "C:\Users\adedi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\adedi\Documents\Dev\Projects\Django\dj-cms\projcms\wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>  
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "C:\Users\adedi\Documents\Dev\Projects\Django\dj-cms\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
    return WSGIHandler()
  File "C:\Users\adedi\Documents\Dev\Projects\Django\dj-cms\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 127, in __init__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "C:\Users\adedi\Documents\Dev\Projects\Django\dj-cms\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 40, in load_middleware
    middleware = import_string(middleware_path)
  File "C:\Users\adedi\Documents\Dev\Projects\Django\dj-cms\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 15, in import_string
    raise ImportError("%s doesn't look like a module path" % dotted_path) from err
ImportError: djangocms_text_ckeditor doesn't look like a module path

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\adedi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\adedi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 946, in run  
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\adedi\Documents\Dev\Projects\Django\dj-cms\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\adedi\Documents\Dev\Projects\Django\dj-cms\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 138, in inner_run
    handler = self.get_handler(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\adedi\Documents\Dev\Projects\Django\dj-cms\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\management\commands\runserver.py", line 27, in get_handler
    handler = super().get_handler(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\adedi\Documents\Dev\Projects\Django\dj-cms\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 65, in get_handler
    return get_internal_wsgi_application()
  File "C:\Users\adedi\Documents\Dev\Projects\Django\dj-cms\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 47, in get_internal_wsgi_application
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application 'projcms.wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing module.
```

I have inspected my code and can't seem to find any answer.

Comment: Can you include your middleware setting? The error suggests that's where your problem is.

Comment: It’s been resolved. I restarted the process and it worked